# how to pinch-zoom and zoom on double tap in view group in android 2.3

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, viewgroup, pinchzoom

In my android application i want to perform the pinch zoom functionality on a view (not image view).
I also want to zoom the view-group on double-tap event.i did it by using a canvas but i think this is not the exact solution. please suggest the solution to my problem.
thanks in advance.....